# Python cheatsheet for beginners?

Tags: python

I've seen the cheatsheet floating around the web, but I'm after something that shows assigning variables; creating literals, tuple, lists, dictionaries, sets; accessing lists, disctionaries; list of operators; list of datatype functions etc..

..so something that I memorize and remember easily.

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but I suggest you to try out http://code.he.net 's interactive courses to learn the basics of the language :)

Comment: Thanks, its actually useful! But I know the basics, I just keep forgetting them due to lack of practice, so I want something that I can write it down or print, memorize and always refer to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Cheatsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776265/python-cheatsheet)

Comment: https://github.com/cirosantilli/python-cheat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Python Quick Reference (PQR), latest versions available from http://rgruet.free.fr/. It is updated for each new version by different people.

Comment: However, there hadn't been updates for Python 3+.